# Google Earth KML Folder Point descriptions clean-up

Tags: kml

Having trouble figuring out how to fix the Folder with my point description. The picture I added shows you 2 different point description styles. One has the main point name and popup info underneath while the other is CLEAN doesn't have the popup info underneath. 
[image]

I converted both these files from ArcGis 10.2 and they both come out different. I looked at the HTML code (novice with code) and nothing seems different besides the info....

I can seem to get the code to post here.

Comment: Clean placemark HTML description: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6qcnon7mbmer0m/CLEAN_code.docx?dl=0

Comment: Other placemark HTML description - not clean: https://www.dropbox.com/s/txsedm1etiitep0/dirty_code.docx?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

The info below the feature name in the My Places list view is called the "snippet".  In KML you can explicitly add a `<snippet>` tag to define that text. If no snippet is defined in the KML, it will by default use the first line or two of the content in the `<description>` tag. That is most likely what you're seeing, though I can't confirm since your dropbox links are no longer available.

To remove or suppress the snippet, you can insert an empty snippet tag (`<snippet></snippet>`) just above the `<description>` tag in each KML feature. That requires editing the KML manually, via find/replace in a text editor, or via a script of some sort.  I don't know if ArcGIS has options for exporting KML with the snippets suppressed.